# Identify existing clients by event

Tags: google-analytics

I'm interested in working out how many visitors are going to my site who aren't already clients.

Currently the only way to identify whether someone visiting the site is an existing client is if they log in, which takes them to another area which doesn't have google analytics enabled.

I'm tracking the event already when they login with the following code

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Membership', 'Login', $('#UserName').val()]);
```

Can I find out the number of visitors who browse the site without triggering this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I've worked it out.

In google analytics you can add a custom advanced segment, in the above case its 'Event Category' = 'Membership' and 'Event Action' = 'Login'.
From there you can tick 'All Visits' and the custom segment to get a comparison.

[image: Audience]